# Angular Universal Deployment on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, angular-universal

I have converted my angular9 Application to Angular Universal and now i want to deploy on IIS server.This works fine when i add a site but whe i add a application in DEfault Web Site of IIS this shows following error.
Images are here.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksWw2.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk27S.png

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously that you are running an incorrect rewrite rule for your application. When the rule can't rewrite your extensionless URL, then IIS static file handler will handle it.

If you enable failed request tracing, then you may notcie that

[image]

its input match is blank"" instead of /appraisal.

So if main.js is placed in appraisal/server/

Then please try this rule

```
 <rule name="rewrite rule">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server/main.js" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/appraisal/*" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

Comment: i have added this but after that i am having 404 Page not found error.